# Как закрыть терминал с AWS EC2 без выключения сервера

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, putty, ec2

У меня есть `instance aws ec2` на платформе `Amazon Linux`.
Работаю через `PuTTY`.
Есть проблема, при закрытие терминала, выключается севрер(програмы перестают работать), на виндовс сервере такого не было.

Возможно стоит сменить `SSH` клиент?
Или есть какие-то другие способы для закрытия терменала без выключения самого сервера?

Comment: Потом что бы подключиться вы включаете сервер заново? Или у вас просто все программы из сессии закрываются? Если все запущенный программы закрываются, то попробуйте почитать про `screen` например или запускать программы отвязывая их от сессии `command & disown`

Comment: Сервером вы ведь тут называете код, а не хост?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы серверное ПО работало независимо от терминала, запускать его должен процесс-демон, который инициализируются вместе с запуском Линукса и живёт независимо от создания/завершения SSH-сессий. Вариантов для этого много:

1. Самый правильный способ – использовать менеджер служб, например стандартный Линуксовый [SystemD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd). Примеров настройки своих служб через него много, вот например на [Хабре: Systemd за пять минут](https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/255845/). Менеджеры служб хороши тем, что имеют массу настроек (перезапуски, количество рабочих процессов и т.д), предоставляют удобный интерфейс запуска/остановки службы, отображают логи, и в принципе являются переиспользуемым решением.
2. Есть и более простые варианты. Например можно запускать через команду `nohup`, тоже стандартная утилита Линукс. Либо да, `tmux`, который позволяет создавать сессии терминала независимые от SSH. Минусы этих решений:

- Не очень переиспользуемо
- Процесс сложно убивать/пересоздавать вручную – для этого ещё надо найти айдишник нужного процесса.
- При возникновении ошибки и падении службы автоматического перезапуска не произойдёт.
- При перезапуске хоста служба не запустится автоматически. А менеджеры служб вроде SystemD это делают по умолчанию `;)`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ. Для этого нужно использовать screen или tmux(мой вариант)